# Inbound changeset not showing up in target organization

Tags: deployment, change-set

I am trying to deploy a change set and even though I have received the email notifying me that it is ready, nothing appears in the target organization. This is after multiple successful uploads earlier today with the same users. Is there anything that could be causing this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sometimes it just takes a while before it shows up. It can sometimes take 20-30 minutes or more to even appear in the list. Even then it can take MORE time to actually be deployable.

If it's been more than an hour and you still don't see it then you may want to double check that you're deploying to the correct target organization.

Comment: I was under the impresion that once the email came through, it was ready

Comment: That should be the case, but that isn't always how it works out. I use it as an excuse to take long lunches :)

Comment: If it's been more than an hour and it's still missing, contact Salesforce Support. I had a changeset get "stuck" once, and needed their assistance to remove it from the queue.

Comment: @Sdry: Obligitory [XKCD reference](http://xkcd.com/303/)

Comment: @BobRoberts : Ha! didn't even need to open it to know which one it was going to be :D

Answer (score 1):

@Sdry A good one haha!

The availability of change sets in the target org can vary between 3 to 30 mins. Same goes with when deploying - deployment can go through in less than 5 mins or can take 45 minutes depending on the number of tests being run.

Comment: I've had a deploy take 1.5 hours to run, at 2am on AP1.  It was a VERY large deployment.

Comment: The deployments and uploads are both queued processes. So, if other clients on the same instance are deploying before you are, your deployment will generally take longer. A week back just an upload of a class took 4 hours for me!